# JPA Multiple EntityManagerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Current project that I've been working on contains a lot of separate modules that i don't have access.
The task is to use JPA in my module, and set to it own EnitityManagerFactory. The problem that defining second EnitityManagerFactory bean in applicationContext.xml cause error in module, that I don't access (admin module ).

Nature of the error - Spring can't understand which bean to use in admin module and I can't solve by:

```
@PersistenceContext( name = "adminDataSource" )
private EntityManager  entityManager;
```

with no access source code of it.

any advice ?

EDITED:

meantime here is part of application context file that shows the problem.
so if uncomment bean below, Spring will throw exception in other module that i don't have access.

```
<!--bean   
        class = "org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id = "slotsEntityManagerFactory" >
    <property 
                name="persistenceUnitName" 
                value="spinPersistence"/>
    <property 
                name="dataSource" ref="slotsDataSource"/>
    <property 
                name="packagesToScan" 
                value="com.win.server.protocol.http.spin" />
</bean -->

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
     <property 
                name="persistenceUnitName" 
                value=""/>
     <property 
                name="packagesToScan" 
                value="com.win.slots" />

    <property name="dataSource" ref="adminDataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL"/> <!-- HSQL --> 
            <property name="showSql" value="false"/> 
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/> 
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried @Autowired the entitymanager from spring application context?

Comment: basically application context has to have to entities factory and this is the problem. so when i add second EntityManagerFactory bean to application context, spring gives me error in module that i don't have access to, as it can't choose which bean to use.